# Why +ve charge(conventional current) flows out of the -ve terminal of a battery?

Tags: capacitor, current, capacitance, homework, emf

[image]

Please consider question 45 part c. In this question if I consider that the capacitor after being fully charged at 24V is now connected to a 12V battery, and since some heat will be lost as charge travels from one capacitor plate to the other, I assume a resistance is connected between the +ve terminal of the 12V battery and the +vely charged plate of the capacitor.

Now, I have 3 doubts-
• as the connections are completed, a current starts flowing from the +ve plate of capacitor to the +ve terminal of battery due to a potential difference between the two, as the +ve charges(due to conventional current) reach the +ve terminal of the 12V battery, please explain why the +ve charges then move to the -ve terminal of battery? Will the battery mechanism not try to keep the +ve charges attached to the +ve terminal?(please explain in terms of conventional current)

•Once the +ve charges reach the -ve terminal of the battery why do they leave the -ve terminal to the -ve plate of the capacitor? (There is no resistance between the two, so no potential difference to cause the charges to flow), also will the -ve charges on the -ve terminal of battery not bind the +ve charges to it?(I know current must make a round trip in a closed circuit, but the circuit is not complete anyways here, due to the capacitor)

•If work is done on the battery, then why doesn't the potential difference between it's terminals increase?

I know homework questions are not allowed, but I just used the question as an example for addressing a number of similar doubts I encounter while solving problems.

Thank you.

Comment: No charge flew through the battery. (Flown is the past participle of to fly, not to flow.)

Comment: "I know homework questions are not allowed* They are, to the extent that you first work on them.

Comment: @MiNiMe , yeah, but I am stuck in these doubts, can you help with them please?